# Python Firewall for Windows?

Tags: python, windows, security, firewall

I want to write a tiny custom firewall for windows, in python. I would be very glad if someone can point me in the right direction to achieve this. I would like to have block/unblock IP and Port.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Driver_Interface_Specification

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189138/is-it-possible-to-write-a-firewall-in-python

Answer (score 0):

### Use python's subprocess module to run the following command prompt / powershell commands:

Configure the Windows firewall service to start automatically.

```
sc config mpssvc start=auto
```

Start the Windows firewall service.

```
net stop mpssvc && net start mpssvc
```

Enable the Windows firewall profiles.

```
netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state on
```

Create a firewall rule to deny the input of packets from a specific IP address.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="BLOCK IP ADDRESS - 10.10.10.10" dir=in action=block remoteip=10.10.10.10
```

Create a firewall rule to deny the output of packets to a specific IP address.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="BLOCK IP ADDRESS - 10.10.10.10" dir=out action=block remoteip=10.10.10.10
```