# Is it possible to write simple Firewall with Python/Scapy for Windows?

Tags: windows, firewall, scapy

I'm looking to make a "small" firewall that can intercept HTTP traffic,  it should then modify or drop the packet according to its ip address and the content(text) of the packet.

I googled several times before I created this question.
Im afraid it'll take a long time, also, I do not have any experience in developing a [driver kernel-mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-Mode_Driver_Framework).

Recently though, I came across a library for python [(scapy)](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/), and from the [documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/), it is able to sniff as well as forge traffic.

However I have a few questions about scapy:

What does it mean to "forge network packets?" Does it forge a copy of the packets?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Also since I'm not experienced in developing drivers in kernel-mode, is there any alternative library in user-mode? The programming language used is not my goal, my goal is to accomplish this task in a short period of time and as simply as it can be done.

Comment: First, it's an "Is it possible?" question, which can only have two answers (yes/no). Second, there's no real specific question about programming here; there's a question about the definition of a networking term. Third, you didn't search very hard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189138/is-it-possible-to-write-a-firewall-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064561/python-firewall-for-windows. Third, we're not [personal research assistants](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/102937). We can answer specific programming questions; this one's too vague.

Comment: Also, what have you tried, do you have and sample code that tries to accomplish the problem you have, or is this just where should i get started type of question?

Comment: "you didn't search very hard" the link is talking about firewall on linux os not in windows(I have already gone through it).  "We're not personal research assistants" I have not asked for PRA...

Comment: Sometimes people if they do not understand the question or they do not have an answer, they have fun with the downvote without arguing their act...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also since I'm not experienced in developing drivers in kernel-mode, is there any alternative library in user-mode?

Yes, have a look at my project called [WinDivert](http://reqrypt.org/windivert.html).  WinDivert lets you capture/modify/drop packets from a user-mode application (no kernel programming required).