# using scapy/python to integrate AP to scapy TCP/IP stack

Tags: python, sockets, firewall, scapy, wifi

Needed to know if there is any way in python/scapy to create a wireless AP that links with the scapy TCP/IP stack so I can intercept communications flowing through the stack? What I am aiming to achieve is to create a wlan access point and use scapy to implement a system for sniffing packets sent to that interface and its clients and then choose to reject/accept packets based on rules, think firewall. I am not very skilled in python and my job doesn't even involve infosec or programming. This is a hobby that I have and I don't know as much as some of you guys reading this but I was hoping to find a solution to my problem.

I am using kali linux on my macbook pro.

Comment: Which OS, Windows or Linux?

Comment: Oh am using Kali Linux.

Comment: There is no one line answer to your question, but it is possible to create a virtual access point with linux using tools like `hostapd`. After that you can use scapy to sniff frames on this wireless interface. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808097/is-it-possible-to-write-simple-firewall-with-python-scapy-for-windows